# Firebase iOS SDK + GTM + Analytics category not set

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm currently trying to send hits using the Firebase SDK. Everything works fine, except I can't make 'Firebase Event Name' be send to 'Analytics Category' unless I explicitly send an 'event' parameter, which shouldn't be needed, since the SDK method is logEvent(withName:).

This is what happens: [GA - Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39029.png) 
It does work if I do:

```
Analytics.logEvent("Mapa", parameters: [
        "event": "Mapa",
        "action": "TapOn",
        "label": "test",
        "cd1": "4321"
        ])
```

However, it doesn't work if:

```
Analytics.logEvent("Mapa", parameters: [
        "action": "TapOn",
        "label": "test",
        "cd1": "4321"
        ])
```

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are sending GA Event based on this "Mapa" event - you need to specify category. Event Category is a required parameter for GA Event.

You will see these events in Firebase (and GTM), but Google Analytics will reject event hit without category.

Please see this page for more details.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ec

> Event Action. Required for event hit type. Specifies the event action. Must not be empty.